# Laravel giving me undefined variable error for a different page?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

so I'm having an issue with a laravel project and it makes no sense to me why this is happening, so maybe someone out there has experienced this.

In my home page, I load a partial, we'll call it:  `_homeContent.blade.php`. In the controller for the home page, I am pinging an API, gathering data and returning it to the home page, as a `$quotes` variable.

So:

```
return view('home', compact('quotes'));
```

In my view, I have the loop:

```
@foreach($quotes as $quote)
    I do my loop things here.
@endforeach
```

So that works fine, no issues, the data is coming in as I expect it to. Further down the page, I have a link to another page. Just a standard a href="/my-about-page" for example.  When I click it, I get an error that says:

> Undefined variable: quotes(View: /my/path/here/_homeContent.blade.php)

Question is: Why am I getting this error on my about page, telling me that there is an undefined variable on `_homeContent.blade.php`. I was just on the home page and it worked, I leave the page, and it breaks the next page.

Comment: You are trying to use the `$quotes` variable on the next page and the variable doesn't exist. Hence the error saying "undefined variable". The variable hasn't been defined on that page before you use it. It may have been defined on the other page, but each request has it's own set of variables. They don't share.

Comment: Wrap     foreach around    if(isset($quotes))  endif

Comment: Please show your layout file, maybe you use the same layout for both pages and want to access $quotes, but it is not defined.